# How do I loading exactly the URL I typed, not Google Search of the same URL with a fragment specifier in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, url, chromium, address-bar

I paste a `file:///path/to/my/page.html` into Chromium. Under the address bar appears:

- file:///path/to/my/page.html - Google Search
- file:///path/to/my/page.html#somefragment - My Page

If I just press Enter, it does the Google Search.

If I choose (but not click) at the entry with fragment, then manually backspace it, it also turns into a Google Search request when I erase it to `file:///path/to/my/page.html#`.

If I click away from address bar to let the search suggestion disappear, then re-enter address bar, then press Enter, it enters Google Search.

In Privacy Settings, various options about address bar like "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" are already turned off.

Comment: `file:///` has too many `/` characters ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, No, it's just right. First two slashes are for `file://` schema, the third slash is for `/path/to/my/page.html` UNIX path.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: delete the offending auto-complete entry:

- Paste the URL into address bar
- Select the auto-suggest entry with keyboard
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- Title of the entry (in the example, "My Page") should disappear
- Re-paste the URL into address bar if needed
- Press Enter